# Google App Engine model for Select Box

Tags: google-app-engine, django-models, google-datatable

I have category model, in which I want to load some default data. How can I achieve it? This is model is for a select box, which is extensible for different applications later

This is the model I have designed it, I tried verifying choice

```
class Category(db.Model):
    categorylist=db.StringListProperty()
```

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: How and where is the default data stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Box Model

```
Class Category (db.Model):
       name = db.StringProperty()
```

Right now, I use this in this fashion (I'm using Django Framework).

In the views.py I make an array

```
options =["Car", "Motor Bikes", "Bikes", "Apparel"]
```

and in the templates I populate it this way

```
{% for option in options %}
   {% ifequal edit_nw.category option %}
         {{option}}
    {% else %}
         {{option}}     
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

All I want is to use this options to be a result of model like Category.all(), should have some default data loaded for the entire app. If necessary, Ill add categories from admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html). There is `default` attribute for property.

> default
>   A default value for the
>   property. If the property value is
>   never given a value, or is given a
>   value of None, then the value is
>   considered to be the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the help Vladimir..! I've looked into it, but what I wanted is to store list of values for one field of the model...I was not able to figure out, how to do store multiple default values for a category model. Here is my Model <pre><code> ,                 class Category:                                                                name = db.StringProperty();                                                </code></pre> If have to tell in a normal relational database type, something like in a table category, I need some default categories to be stored, so I can add them from backend

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. How is that possible to have multiple default values. Can you show me an example? IS that what you mean `name = db.StringProperty(default=["default1", "default2"]);`?

Comment: Example is a select box options, I want to store all of the options values as in Model. Yes <code>name = db.StringProperty(default=["default1", "default2"]);</code>, May be this.let me try and update here back, however thank you for your patience in addressing my problem.